# Conversion from string to date in swift returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have a problem with converting the string to date in swift 3. Here is my code, it returns me a nil value while converting.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss +zzzz"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "bg_BG")

let recdate = dateFormatter.date(from:"Fri, 10 Mar 2017 15:03:03 +0530")!;`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You set the wrong format specifier for hour and timezone. Use this:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
```

- `hh` means 12-hour format so there's no hour 15. Use `HH` instead
- `+zzzz` is invalid timezone specifier. Use `Z` instead
- Unless Friday is shortened to `Fri` in Bulgarian, use an English locale

Comment: tried this **E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z** and  **EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z** , Still not working . Im still getting **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-03-13 08:52:50.557530 Dubber[1851:1317294] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Comment: @nikhil Try `dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current`, I don't have idea why the "bg_BG" doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of problems, first, as pointed out by Code Different, you need to be using HH to read 24-hour times.  But, you're also specifying a locale, which means that the "word" portions must be in bulgarian, not english.  Leaving the language the default seems to work fine:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +zzzz"
//dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "bg_BG")
let recdate = dateFormatter.date(from:"Fri, 10 Mar 2017 15:03:03 +0530")!
```

If you were to use Bulgarian day and month names, your format should work.

```
dateFormatter.date(from:"нд, 10 март 2017 15:03:03 +0530")
```